# Banco de Dados Portável para WPF + C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, wpf

Estou criando um formulário em WPF + C# no VS Express 2013 for Desktop.

Existe algum banco de dados similar ao SQLite que eu possa usar com o C#+WPF?

Pois como venho do desenvolvimento em Delphi me acostumei a sempre ter que instalar um servidor para o banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que você pode usar próprio SQLite.
Veja este tópico.
[Clique Aqui][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432730/using-sqlite-net-in-a-wpf-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode instalar um SQL Express, ou utilizar um arquivo .mdf do SQL, Access, MySQL, Firebird o que quiser, em .NET você é livre pra ser feliz :)

Para estudo recomendo o SQL Express, até mesmo para pequenas applicações(médias em alguns casos)

Fora isso, um SQL Standard ou outra versão estará ótima.

(Dê preferência ao Azure, o futuro está aí ;))